# Melhorar uma busca no Banco

Tags: php, mysql, orientação-a-objetos, codeigniter

Gostaria de uma ajuda de melhorias em uma Query de Busca hoje cada Busca que o usuario faz no campo de busca eu dou um OR no meu Where
 Gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma melhor de fazer isso pois vou precisar colocar mas 5 opções de busca para o usuario

**Uma unica busca para tudo conforme a imagem abaixo**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
// CONFIGURAÇÃO DO FILTRO

if(isset($_POST['filtro_busca'])){

  // Recupero os valores
  $conteudo['value_busca']  = $this->input->post('filtro_busca'     , TRUE);

}
```

Uma parte do Controller aonde busco preciso colocar mais 5 parametros nessa busca ou seja mais 5 **"OR"**

```
$where .= " AND (
     nome like '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%'
  OR email like '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%'
  OR telefone_1 like '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%'
  OR rg like '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%'
  OR cpf like '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%'
  OR codigo like '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%'
) ";
```

Comment: Pelo que percebi você está fazendo a busca retornar valores que não deveriam, pois pelo meu entendimento não deveria usar `Like` nos campos `Telefone, RG, CPF, CODIGO`, pelo fato de ser campos inteiros;

Comment: @Aprendiz não dá para afirmar que são inteiros, eu mesma coloco como `VARCHAR` porque prefiro que as máscaras sejam salvas com no banco. Shaolin, você está usando um campo de buscar para todos esses itens? Ficou meio confuso.

Comment: Isso mesmo @DiéfaniFavaretoPiovezan um campo de buscar para todos os itens na verdade esse código ja esta rodando ja faz um tempo foi feito por outro cara queria dar uma melhorada deixar mais automatizado

Comment: O que eu quero dizer, poderia verificar o que o usuário digitou, se foi um numero então só busca em determinados campos, já que os campos são todos `VARCHAR` assim ia reduzir bastante o tempo de resposta

Comment: Você pode fazer um campo que tem todas as strings dos outros campos e buscar só esse campo grande. Pode usar um trigger do banco pra atualizar esse campo de busca, ou alterar o campo na hora de update e insert.

Comment: Cara falando em autonomia, só faça com um item, vai saber qual tamanho do seu banco, se for grande você vai rodar o banco inteiro para achar uma pessoa só com todos essas colunas

Answer (score 2):

Se você não sabe em qual campo estará o valor procurado ou até sabe mas quer fazer uma busca geral nos campos usando o valor digitado, o ideal é fazer um `SELECT` e usar `CONCAT` dentro da clausula `WHERE`, dessa forma os campos que você precisa serão concatenados e a busca será feita dentro deles. É importante colocar as aspas simples após cada nome dos campos para separar os valores. De uma forma geral o `SELECT` deveria ser assim:

```
SELECT * FROM tabela WHERE CONCAT(Campo1, '', Campo2, '', Campo3, '', Campon) LIKE '%valor%'
```

Para seu mais exata, seu código ficará

```
$where .= " AND CONCAT(nome, '', email, '', telefone, '', rg, '', cpf, '', codigo) LIKE '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%' )";
```

Se houver problemas com **Case Sensitivity**, você pode tornar tudo **Case Insensitive**

```
$where .= " AND LOWER(CONCAT(nome, '', email, '', telefone, '', rg, '', cpf, '', codigo)) LIKE LOWER('%{$condicao['value_busca']}%' ))";
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode criar um `<select>` para o usuário escolher o filtro que deseja utilizar.

Por exemplo:

```
    <select name="filtro">
       <option value="fNomeEmail">Nome e E-Mail</option>
       <option value="fTel">Telefone</option>
       <option value="fRgCpf">RG/CPF</option>
       <option value="fCod">Código</option>
    </select>
```

Daí você monta o SQL só com o filtro desejado não tendo que buscar em todos os campos da tabela.

```
   $where .= " AND (";
   if ($_POST['filtro'] == 'fNomeEmail') $where .= "nome like '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%' OR email like '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%' ";
   if ($_POST['filtro'] == 'fTel') $where .= "OR telefone_1 like '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%' ";
   if ($_POST['filtro'] == 'fRgCpf') $where .= "OR rg like '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%' OR cpf like '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%' ";
   if ($_POST['filtro'] == 'fCod') $where .= "OR codigo like '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%'";
    $where .= ")";
```

Ou pode fazer desta forma também, verificando se ele digitou números e assim montar o SQL:

```
   $caracteres = array("(", ")", "-", ".", "+", " ");
   $soNumero = str_replace($caracteres, "", $condicao['value_busca']);

   $where .= " AND (";
   if (is_numeric($soNumero)) {
     $where .= "telefone_1 LIKE '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%' OR rg LIKE '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%' OR cpf LIKE '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%' OR codigo LIKE '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%'";
   } else {
     $where .= "nome LIKE '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%' OR email LIKE '%{$condicao['value_busca']}%'";
   }            
   $where .= ")";
```